# How to split the string value in one column on access table using vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've a table contains the columns like

```
Prefix    CR
g         ;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;# 
v         ;#WR_3;#WR_4;#
j         WR_2
m         WR_1
d         ;#WR_3;#WR_4;#   
f9        WR_3
```

I'm finding largest string in the column **CR** as **;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#** Using

```
    select top 1 CR,Prefix from table1 order by len(CR) desc
```

And returns

```
Prefix        CR
g             ;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#
```

I wanted to split this string **;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#** as Column names like

```
Prefix  WR_1    WR_2   WR_3   WR_4
```

Or As an array

```
WR_1
WR_2
WR_3
WR_4
```

Comment: What data would populate the columns?

Comment: Data can be null , because i wanted to use these column names in dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't a very pretty solution, but it does as you ask:

```
create table #Blah(Prefix nvarchar(5), CR nvarchar(60))

insert into #Blah
values('g', ';#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#')
insert into #Blah
values('v', ';#WR_3;#WR_4;#')
insert into #Blah
values('j', 'WR_2')
insert into #Blah
values('m', 'WR_1')
insert into #Blah
values('d', ';#WR_3;#WR_4;#')
insert into #Blah
values('f9', 'WR_3')

SELECT Prefix, [WR_1], [WR_2], [WR_3], [WR_4]
FROM(
    SELECT Prefix, SUBSTRING(CR+';#', num, CHARINDEX(';#', CR+';#', num) - num) Item, convert(int,NULL) Col
    FROM #Blah 
        inner join Numbers on num <= LEN(REPLACE(CR,' ','|')) AND SUBSTRING(';#' + CR, num, LEN(REPLACE(';#',' ','|'))) = ';#'
    WHERE SUBSTRING(CR+';#', num, CHARINDEX(';#', CR+';#', num) - num) > ''
    ) q
PIVOT (
    MAX(Col) FOR Item IN ([WR_1], [WR_2], [WR_3], [WR_4])
) p

drop table #Blah
```

This query uses a table called `Numbers` which just uses a single column `Num` which has a row for every number from 1 to 10,000.

I'm not sure why having the data as column headers would be useful in populating a drop down list, to get the data as rows, simply remove the pivot and just use the inner query, aliased `q`

Comment: I'm using Access-VBA, how can i define FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString].

Comment: hmm must have missed that tag, I'm not sure if it's possible.  I'll rewrite the answer so it doesn't use a table-valued function.

Comment: @swa1234 Answer has been edited to remove the table-valued function.  Still not 100% sure it will work in Access-VBA